# What is meant by a large subgroup?

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, terminology, definition

> What is the meaning of a large subgroup in following paper?

[image: this]

> Is it equal to "maximal subgroup"?

Comment: Um... a subgroup that is large, perhaps?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork .so large subgroup means "mapping onto a non-cyclic free group" ?

Comment: If the authors wanted to say "maximal", they would say so. The definition must be on page 2 (or 3, 4, 5) of the paper.

Comment: @amir Your definition of large in your above comment is incorrect. The "large" in your comment requires finite-index (see Shaun's answer). Sometimes, people call subgroups which map into non-abelian free groups "very large". (This is irrelevant to the paper by JCAA's answer, but I thought I should correct it anyway.)

Answer (score 5):

The paper is Hatcher, Allen(1-CRNL); Lochak, Pierre(F-ENS-MI); Schneps, Leila(F-FRANS-LM)
On the Teichmüller tower of mapping class groups. (English summary)
J. Reine Angew. Math. 521 (2000), 1–24.

The subgroup $\Lambda$ they construct is defined before Theorem A on page 3. The meaning of "large" is explained in Theorems B, C, D. It is just the colloquial "large" which has nothing to do with the standard definitions of largeness in the literature.

Comment: What is "1-CRNL" ?

Comment: Department of Mathematics
Cornell University
Ithaca NY 14853

Comment: Lochak: Department of Mathematics and Computer Science (DMI)
École Normale Supérieure
75230 Paris
FRANCE

Schneps:Mathematics Laboratory
Faculty of Sciences
University of Franche-Comté (Besançon)
25030 Besançon
FRANCE

Answer (score 2):

> **Definition:** A *large* group is a group with a finite index subgroup that maps onto the free group $F_2$ of rank $2$.

This is a definition I work with in my research. I'm not sure whether it's the one intended in the paper you cite though.

*Edit:* I see that you have described something like this definition in your comment.

Answer (score 1):

This terminology is not completely standard but:

> A subgroup is said to be large if any subgroup that intersects it trivially must be the trivial subgroup.

Source:  https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Large_subgroup

As I said, the terminology is not standard, so you may find other definitions. For instance, in [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1631073X1830061X) a subgroup is said to be large if it contains its centralizer.